# Pandas keep square brackets in to_latex output

Tags: python, pandas, latex

I have a dataframe that I need to pass to a LaTeX document. The dataframe index are strings with square brackets that I would like to keep.

MWE:

```
data = {
  "calories": [420, 380, 390],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, index = ['[1] Row 1', '[2] Row 2','[3] Row 3'])

print(df.to_latex(index=True))
```

Output of print(to_latex):

```
           calories  duration
[1] Row 1       420        50
[2] Row 2       380        40
[3] Row 3       390        45
>>> print(df.to_latex(index=True))
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
\toprule
{} &  calories &  duration \\
\midrule
[1] Row 1 &       420 &        50 \\
[2] Row 2 &       380 &        40 \\
[3] Row 3 &       390 &        45 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

The output of `to_latex` does not show the square brackets in between `{}` as `{[1]}`, so it would yield an error when compiled in LaTeX.
If I add the `{}` to the python index name string, this will be shown in the code too as `\{[1]\}` and show in the LaTeX document as `{[1]}`, but I want the LaTeX document to show `[1]`.

How could I get `[1]` in my LaTeX document?

Comment: but `[` is not a special LaTeX character, it should be displayed just fine? Pass `escape=False` to `to_latex` if you don't want it turn `{` into `\{`.